# How to convert a navbar in react to a window title bar in electron app based on the same react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, titlebar

so I am looking for converting a nav bar on the webpage created in react to be a title bar in electron app. Just like how slack has it's search bar in the below images.

Is it possible to have the electron take the same code of HTML that react uses in the browser to act as a title bar.

PS: I want to have the close, minimize, maximize buttons in the title bar on left alongside my widgets at the center.

[image: Slack search bar in browser]

[image: Slack search bar as a title bar in macOS app]